# What is lack in sense of smell called?

Tags: physiology

People who lack the sense of hearing, vision and speaking are called *Deaf*, *Blind* and *Mute*.
But what is the person called if he/she lacks the sense of smell? Is there any case like that?

Answer (score 6):

This condition is called 'anosmia', see these two links: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anosmia) and from the british [National Health Service](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/anosmia/Pages/Introduction.aspx). They include a definition and reasons for anosmia.

Comment: the person would be called 'anosmic'. See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anosmic